# Checking if records exists in a table from a 1-billion row table

Tags: php, mysql

I have a data scraping script that runs and scrapes records, saves into the following table:

[image]

For the records already existing in DB, I need to update the old records if it is not updated for the past 2 days.

My table has fields `scraper_run_inserted` (DATETIME value when record is inserted) and `scraper_run_updated` (DATETIME value when record is updated). That table has 1 billion rows.

```
<?php

// this will be used to get records from DB which are not updated for the past N day(s)
$prev_date_to_check = date('Y-m-d H:i:s', strtotime('-2 day', strtotime($date_scraper_ran)));

// get all licence_id from all rows which were updated within last 2 days ... 
$doNotupdateLicencesList = "SELECT DISTINCT(licence_id) FROM `{$onegov_main_table}` WHERE scraper_run_updated >= '{$prev_date_to_check}'";
$doNotupdateLicencesList = $conn->prepare($doNotupdateLicencesList);
$doNotupdateLicencesList->execute();
$doNotupdateLicencesList = $doNotupdateLicencesList->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_COLUMN);

// GET all postcodes from DB
$oneGovPostCodes = "SELECT CONCAT(city, ', ' ,postcode) FROM `{$oneGovPostCodesTable}`";
$oneGovPostCodes = $conn->prepare($oneGovPostCodes);
$oneGovPostCodes->execute();
$oneGovPostCodes = $oneGovPostCodes->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_COLUMN);

// iterate over all POST CODES 
foreach ($oneGovPostCodes as $postCode) {


    $allLicencesOnThisPage = get_licences('www.website.com?postcode='.$postCode);
//    $allLicencesOnThisPage contains licence_ids as its index
//    example: array(
//        'licence_id_1' => array(/*data*/),
//        'licence_id_2' => array(/*data*/),
//        );


    foreach ($doNotupdateLicencesList as $l) {
        if (isset($allLicencesOnThisPage[$l])) {
            unset($allLicencesOnThisPage[$l]);
        }
    }

    // now start iterating over array of Licences
    foreach ($allLicencesOnThisPage as $licenceID => $licence) {


        $dataArray = get_licence_page($url);

        $ins_query = 'INSERT INTO `' . $table_name . '`(licence_id,licenceNumber, licenceName,licensee,status,licenceTypeName,startDate,expiryDate,address,addressType, externalClaims, internalClaims, publicWarnings, payload, suburb, postcode, scraper_run_inserted) '
                . 'VALUES(:licence_id,:licenceNumber, :licenceName,:licensee,:status,:licenceTypeName,:startDate,:expiryDate,:address,:addressType, :externalClaims, :internalClaims, :publicWarnings, :payload, :suburb, :postcode, CURRENT_TIMESTAMP())'
                . ' ON DUPLICATE KEY '
                . ' UPDATE licenceNumber=:licenceNumber, licenceName=:licenceName ,licensee=:licensee , status=:status , licenceTypeName=:licenceTypeName , startDate=:startDate , expiryDate=:expiryDate ,address=:address, addressType=:addressType ,externalClaims = :externalClaims, internalClaims=:internalClaims, publicWarnings=:publicWarnings, payload=:payload, suburb=:suburb, postcode=:postcode, scraper_run_updated = CURRENT_TIMESTAMP()';
        $stmt = $conn->prepare($ins_query);

        $stmt->bindValue(":licence_id", $dataArray['licence_id']);
        $stmt->bindValue(":licenceNumber", $dataArray['licenceNumber']);
        $stmt->bindValue(":licenceName", $dataArray['licenceName']);
        $stmt->bindValue(":licensee", $dataArray['licensee']);
        $stmt->bindValue(":status", $dataArray['status']);
        $stmt->bindValue(":licenceTypeName", $dataArray['licenceTypeName']);
        $stmt->bindValue(":startDate", $dataArray['startDate']);
        $stmt->bindValue(":expiryDate", $dataArray['expiryDate']);
        $stmt->bindValue(":address", $dataArray['address']);
        $stmt->bindValue(":addressType", $dataArray['addressType']);
        $stmt->bindValue(":externalClaims", $dataArray['externalClaims']);
        $stmt->bindValue(":internalClaims", $dataArray['internalClaims']);
        $stmt->bindValue(":publicWarnings", $dataArray['publicWarnings']);
        $stmt->bindValue(":payload", $dataArray['payload']);
        $stmt->bindValue(":suburb", $dataArray['suburb']);
        $stmt->bindValue(":postcode", $dataArray['postcode']);

        $stmt->execute();
    }
}
```

Comment: It is not clear what "update" operation you are trying to do — there is no `UPDATE` query in your code — nor is it clear that your code successfully accomplishes the task.

Comment: see my edit in question. my goal is achieved. but It is just slow. I want to speed it up.

Comment: Can you show us the real code that does the `REPLACE` then?

Comment: see `edit 2` and `edit 3` .... i tried both

Comment: What indexes are present in this table? Are you able to run `EXPLAIN SELECT` on the query that takes very long, and include the output from that?

Comment: How do these four code snippets fit together?  I think I would have an easier time understanding if you just showed all of your code, exactly as it appears in your program.

Comment: @200_success sir first snippet is to load all licences in DB that are not need to be updated. and in 2nd snippet, code run runs and iterates over all pages of website, for each page, `$allLicencesOnThisPage` contains licence IDs of all licences present on particular page ... 

and then code in `edit 2` or  `edit 3` is being used to save data ....

Comment: Would you mind getting rid of the "Edit 1, Edit 2, …" and making it into one coherent question? Thanks.

Comment: @200_success I have updated question ... please see it now

Comment: Usually, you'd do the `$conn->prepare()` bit just once, outside the loop - that's part of the reason for using it - you don't have to run it multiple times.  And are you sure it's the SQL that's slow?  It looks like the bottleneck's more likely to be the fetch from the remote site (the `get_licences()` call)

Answer (score 2):

`license_id` is the primary key of table, so there is no point in `DISTINCT`ing the field in your case. Also, create an index on the field `scraper_run_updated` to get better query performance.

Another hint maybe is to do you inserts in batch. That would make it much faster, AFAIK. But you loose the benefits of prepared statements, and you have to do the checking yourself.

Basically, instead of filling the prepared statement with values, generate a string like this:

```
INSERT INTO a_table (field1, field2) VALUES (v11, v12),(v21, v22),(v31, v32)
```

You can limit number of values to insert in a batch, like insert 1000 rows each time. Test to see what gives you a good performance. Also consider the memory footprint, as a large string is being generated.

Don't forget to escape the values you are inserting yourself. Use [quote](http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.quote.php) for this purpose.

Comment: I cant use batch insert ... I need to update existing records as well